# Is there a way to loop through recordset and identify different values?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a MS SQL stored Procedure that loops the records of a select statement using a cursor.  When I loop and read each record it could be 3 then 3 then 3 or it could be 3 then 4 and then 5 then 3.  It could be one record or more than one.

What I need to know is are all of the values the same or are they different?  I don't care what they are only if they are the same or different.  If I was doing this with client side code I would use a list and see if that value is in the list then when I'm finished I would count the values if one then the same if more than 1 then different.

```
       DECLARE TC CURSOR LOCAL
             FOR SELECT ProgramID FROM tblPublications
              OPEN TC
              FETCH NEXT FROM TC INTO @ProgramID
              WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
              BEGIN
              Print @ProgramID
               --Same or Different then the last one???


              FETCH NEXT FROM TC2 INTO @ProgramID
              END
              CLOSE TC
              DEALLOCATE TC
        END
```

If they are the same then I will update a record one way and if they are different then update a status record another way.

Thanks

Comment: There is probably a better way to do what you are doing without loops or cursors. Would you expand upon your question?

Comment: We don't want to use loops when counting values in sql. We use aggregates instead. Something like count(YourValue). Give us some actual details about the data and the desired output and we can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have a list of publications that belong to authors that are in various departments.  If all of the authors are from the same department then the publication is considered INTRA department if more that one department was involved in writhing the publication then it is considered INTER department.  My record set contains the department/programid based upon the PublicationID  so-- SELECT ProgramID where PublicationID = 12345-  Now I need to see if the ProgramID's are the same or different

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (no cursor involved) perhaps?

```
select PubId, count(distinct ProgId) 
from tblPublications
group by PubId
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count(distinct col)` to get the number of distinct values for a column, and use a `case` expression to return a value depending on if it is 1 or more.

```
select 
    PublicationId
  , PublicationType = case 
      when count(distinct ProgramId) > 1 
        then 'inter' 
      else 'intra' 
      end
from  tblPublications
where PublicationId = 12345
group by PublicationId
```

Comment: Both you and Giorgos are awesome-- tough to call the correct answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, take care!

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the minimum and maximum of ProgramID in a group.
If all the value is same, the max value will be same as min value.

```
;with tblPublications(ProgramID,ID)AS(
select 'a',1 union 
select 'b',1 union
select 'c',2 union
select 'c',2
```

)

```
select case when ISNULL(max(ProgramID),'')=ISNULL(min(ProgramID),'') then 'Same' else 'Different' end   
from tblPublications
group by ID
```

```
    (No column name)
1   Different
2   Same
```